# Need to restart Linux PC to access via SSH

Tags: networking, server, ssh

Whenever I want to access my 'server' (quotations because it's not set up as a headless server, just used like one) via SSH, I need to restart it. Everything was working fine until around a month ago, (no major OS changes, "server" or client). At the moment I can easily power cycle the server and ssh will start working again fine, but if I leave the set up for more than an hour or so, ssh won't connect again ( connection timeout error).

**Context:**

The ssh config is set up as follows (domain and port are obviously not the real ones):

HostName: my.domain.com (points to static IP)

User: myUserName

Port: 1234 (note: the same config with a different port for a Raspberry Pi works fine all the time)

Router port forwards 1234 to the server.

**'Server':**

Ubuntu 20.04, not configured as headless but I don't regularly have a monitor/keyboard/mouse hooked up.

Dual booted with windows 10 (reused an old PC, didnt want to wipe).

Sits at my feet at my desk.

Sleep and power saving etc are all disabled.

Used for some web dev projects.

**'Client':**

Windows 11 (Windows 10 up until a few days ago)

Usually use vscode to ssh, have tried other terminals.

Comment: It sounds like your server is going to sleep.

Comment: @user68186 Sounds like it could, I'll give it a go

Comment: @user68186, left it over night, seems to have solved the problem, thanks!